# How to define an element using the same element type?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider a `Color` element:

```
<Color x:Key="Color1">#FF1BA1E2</Color>
```

Now, I want to define another `Color` element based on this color with `x:Key="ButtonColor"`, something like this:

```
<Color x:Key="ButtonColor">{StaticResource Color1}</Color>
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Why would you like to do that?! I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: You would probably better declare a SolidColorBrush resource for the Button that uses the `Color1` resource.

Comment: @Bizz because there are another objects that use Color1, and if I want to change the color of buttons, I just change the ButtonColor and not the whole colors. :)

Comment: @Clemens, Color element is just an example, my question is more general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skinning: Using a Color as StaticResource for another Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802419/skinning-using-a-color-as-staticresource-for-another-color)

Comment: @Ed Chapel the answer works fine at runtime but the  designer issue is still unsolved :(