# Is it possible to point one Color resource to another Color resource in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a `Xamarin Forms` Application and I am currently drawing up my application `Resources`, mainly my colours.

For example I have the following:

```
  <Color x:Key="Slate">#404040</Color>
  <Color x:Key="Blue">#458623</Color>

  <Color x:Key="SelectedItemColour">#458623</Color>
```

As you can see my `SelectedItemColour` is the same as the `Blue`.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
  <Color x:Key="Slate">#404040</Color>
  <Color x:Key="Blue">#458623</Color>

  <Color x:Key="SelectedItemColour" Color="{StaticResource Blue}"/>
```

I know if `WPF` you can do the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803872/2987066)

Is it possible to point a `Colour Resource` to another `Colour Resource` in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `x:Static` in tandem with a static class in order to directly reference those colors by name. This has the benefits of keeping the colors centralized into one class and minimizing the amount of XAML.

```
namespace ResourceColors
{
    public static class Colors
    {
        public static Color Slate = Color.FromHex("#404040");
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceColors;assembly=ResourceColors" x:Class="ResourceColors.PageOne">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Blue">#458623</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Test" TextColor="{x:Static local:Colors.Slate}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Does this mean you create a new file Colors.cs? Where do you put it then, in Model, ViewModels, Views or elsewhere? TY

Answer (score 5):

This may be an old question, but I was trying to accomplish this same thing for a project today and wanted a more elegant solution than the one proposed here. There doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish it purely with XAML, but this is the solution I ended up using.

First, I defined a utility class named `ColorReference`:

```cs
public class ColorReference : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color color = Color.Black;

    public Color Color
    {
        get => this.color;
        set
        {
            this.color = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [ NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator ]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([ CallerMemberName ] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    public static implicit operator Color(ColorReference colorReference) => colorReference.Color;
}
```

I'm not 100% positive that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation is necessary but I figured it couldn't hurt (potentially allowing changing the color at runtime; I haven't tested this).

To use it, simply use it as a resource in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```xml
<Color x:Key="FirstColor">#51688f</Color>
...
<utility:ColorReference x:Key="SomeOtherColorName" Color="{StaticResource FirstColor}" />
```

In my use case, I'm using it to style Telerik controls with colors defined in my theme so that if I make a new theme, I don't need to copy the same color value all over the place. The obvious downside is that for any type other than `Color`, a new class would need to be defined, but I doubt I will need too many types to be aliased like this. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future trying to do the same thing I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I had to do this was very complex so listen carefully.

I found that the real problem here was that I needed to "Theme" my Xamarin.Forms application.

So heres what I did.

First made an `abstract Theme` class:

```
public abstract class Theme
{
    public Dictionary<string, Color> Colours { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

    protected void DictionaryThemes(Type type)
    {
        var properties = type.GetRuntimeProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in properties)
        {
            if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
            {
                var key = propInfo.Name;
                var value = propInfo.GetValue(this);
                Colours.Add(key, (Color)value); 
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract Color TitleColour { get; }
}
```

With a nice method using reflection to fill a dictionary full of my `Resources`

I then extended this class with my actual theme:

```
public class MyTheme : Theme
{
    public MyTheme()
    {
        DictionaryThemes(typeof(MyTheme));
    }

    //Slate
    public override Color TitleColour { get; } = Color.FromHex("#00ff00");
}
```

Still with me? good...

I then had to load this theme into my `Application Resources` and merge it with my other application resources. I have to split the `MyTheme` resource from the other `Resources` so that I can use it in my main `Resources` file later.

Let me show you, here is my `CurrentTheme` resource file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:styling="clr-MyApp.Styling;assembly=MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.Styling.CurrentTheme">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
  <styling:MyTheme x:Key="CurrentTheme"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have to do it as part of a page as `Xamarin.Forms` has `Sealed` the `ResourceDictionary` class [(see here)](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-product-suggestions/suggestions/9993753-unseal-resourcedictionary-so-we-can-create-our-own) meaning you can't extend it and create your own.. Shame. Anyway I digress.

I then set my application Resources to `CurrentTheme` like so:

```
 var currentTheme = new CurrentTheme();
 Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources = currentTheme.Resources;
```

I can then merge in other styles from my main `Resource` file, in this case called `Styles`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:styling="clr-MyApp.Styling;assembly=MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.Styling.Styles">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <Style x:Key="TitleStyle" TargetType="Label">
          <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
          <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{styling:Colour TitleColour}" />
       </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I merge this into my main application resources like so:

```
 var styles = new Styles();
 foreach (var item in styles.Resources)
 {
       Application.Current.Resources.Add(item.Key,item.Value);
 }
```

Now as you can see one of the setter properties in the `Styles` class looks like so:

and you're saying whats that value mean?

Here comes the final piece of the puzzle. An extension method that allows you to define your `xaml` like the above.

Firstly the `ColourExtension` class:

```
// You exclude the 'Extension' suffix when using in Xaml markup
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class ColourExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            throw new Exception("No Colour Key Provided");

        return StylingLookup.GetColour(Text);
    }
}
```

and finally the `StylingLookup` class:

```
public static class StylingLookup
{
    public static Color GetColour(string key)
    {
        var currentTheme = (Application.Current.Resources["CurrentTheme"] as Theme);

        return currentTheme.Colours[key];
    }
}
```

And now it all makes sense, Why we had to split `CurrentTheme` from the main `Styles` resources. Because of the line:

```
var currentTheme = (Application.Current.Resources["CurrentTheme"] as Theme);
```

If anyone has a better pattern for *Styling* an application I'd love to hear it

Comment: This has become a lot easier since `MergedDictionaries` were introduces in `Xamarin.Forms` this method can be simplified

Answer (score 0):

@Arconox has the correct answer and here are a few extra tips.

```
public class ReferenceColor
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public ReferenceColor()
    {

    }

    public static implicit operator Color(ReferenceColor referenceColor) => referenceColor.Color;
}
```

Is the code I am using for allowing myself to theme my Xamarin.Forms application at runtime. So to Arconox's point, INotifyPropertyChanged is not required unless you are changing themes/colors after application is running. This allows the use case like this.

```
<Color x:Key="Merlot">#750411</Color>
<local:ReferenceColor x:Key="Page.Static.Background" Color="{StaticResource Merlot}"/>
<Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Page.Static.Background}">
</Grid>
```