# How to Append text to static resource in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, staticresource

I have my resource like this.

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:String x:Key="LabelAutomationIdentifier">LBL_PD_L_PLV_LV_</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

I need to use this resource in the **AutomationId property of Label** like this

```
<Label AutomationId="{StaticResource LabelAutomationIdentifier} + LabelName" />
```

But, this is not correct. I tried multiple ways but no luck.

I tried,

```
<Label AutomationId="{Binding Source={StaticResource LabelAutomationIdentifier}, StringFormat='{}{0}LabelName'}" />
```

also

```
<Label AutomationId="{StaticResource LabelAutomationIdentifier, StringFormat='{0}LabelName'}" />
```

Comment: And what did you try? So we do not repeat the same in our suggestions

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Updated the question.

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044692/1970317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had it been that the `AutomationId` was a bindable property - `<Label AutomationId="{Binding Source={StaticResource LabelAutomationIdentifier}, StringFormat='{}{0}LabelName'}" />` would have worked just fine.

But it is not, and I believe that is the reason the `Binding` won't work in this case. Also, `StaticResource` doesn't have a `StringFormat` property to work with here, so the second option fails.

You can, however extend `StaticResource` extension to create a custom-markup extension to add formatting support.

```
[ContentProperty("StaticResourceKey")]
public class FormatExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string StringFormat { get; set; }
    public string StaticResourceKey { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        string toReturn = null;
        if (serviceProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));

        if (StaticResourceKey != null)
        {
            var staticResourceExtension = new StaticResourceExtension { Key = StaticResourceKey };

            toReturn = (string)staticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringFormat))
                toReturn = string.Format(StringFormat, toReturn);
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

### Sample Usage

```
<Label AutomationId="{local:Format LabelAutomationIdentifier, StringFormat='{0}_LabelName'}" />
```

Comment: @Sharada Can you help with this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392207/how-to-add-incremental-value-for-the-automation-id-of-a-listview-label-in-xamari