# How to add incremental value for the automation id of a Listview label in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have my resource like this

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:String x:Key="LabelAutomationIdentifier">LBL_</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And my listview looks like

```
<ListView 
ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemSource}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label 
                AutomationId="{StaticResource LabelAutomationIdentifier, StringFormat {0}_{Incremental Value OR UniqueIdentifier}'}"
                Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

How to add the incremental value in the automation id?

Answer (score 1):

you can't make when you create the objects??? For example : `var _id = 0;
        MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>
            {
                new MenuItem
                {
                    Id = _id++;
                    Title = "xxxxxxxx",
                },
                 new MenuItem
                {
                    Id = _id++;
                    Title = "yyyyyyyyy",
                },
                 new MenuItem
                {
                    Id = _id++;
                    Title = "zzzzz",
                },
                 new MenuItem
                {
                    Id = _id++;
                    Title = "jjjj",
                },
            };`

Comment: There should be a way to do it as xaml is very extensive and matured. Can you tell me why we can do it and what is the alernate solution? From current answer we need to bind the data which i dont want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but I recently had this same need and couldn't find a good example, so I put this together. If there's a better way, I'd love to see it:

First, make a couple of converters:

```
public class RowNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        int counter = 1;
        if (parameter is Binding && ((Binding)parameter).Source is ListView)
        {
            ListView localListView = (ListView)((Binding)parameter).Source;
            string listViewName = localListView.StyleId;
            foreach (var item in localListView.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (item.GetType() != value.GetType())
                {
                    return null;
                }

                if (item == value)
                {
                    return $"{listViewName}Row{counter}";
                }
                else
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class CellNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return $"{value}.{parameter}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

Reference your converters at the top with the other name space references:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:THE NAMESPACE FOR YOUR CONVERTERS"
```

Here's an example list view:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewResults" 
          AutomationId="listViewResults"
          Margin="0"                       
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
          RefreshCommand="{Binding OnRefresh}"
          SelectionMode="None" 
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <converter:NullableIntConverter x:Key="NullableIntConverter"/>
        <converter:RowNumberConverter x:Key="RowNumberConverter"/>
        <converter:CellNameConverter x:Key="CellNameConverter"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid Margin="5"
                          x:Name="listViewResultsRow"
                          AutomationId="listViewResultsRow">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="260" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="listViewResultsRowNumber" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResultsRow}, Path=BindingContext, Converter={StaticResource RowNumberConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResults}, Path=BindingContext}}" IsVisible="False"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               AutomationId="{Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResultsRowNumber}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CellNameConverter},  ConverterParameter='Column1'}"     
                               Text="{Binding SampleId}" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                               FontSize="Micro" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               AutomationId="{Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResultsRowNumber}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CellNameConverter},  ConverterParameter='Column2'}"     
                               Text="{Binding CancelReason}" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                               FontSize="Micro" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="2" 
                               AutomationId="{Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResultsRowNumber}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CellNameConverter},  ConverterParameter='Column3'}"     
                               Text="{Binding DateCreated, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh\\:mm:ss tt}'}" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                               FontSize="Micro" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="3" 
                               AutomationId="{Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResultsRowNumber}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CellNameConverter},  ConverterParameter='Column4'}"     
                               Text="{Binding LastSyncAttempt, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh\\:mm:ss tt}' }" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                               FontSize="Micro" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="4" 
                               AutomationId="{Binding Source={x:Reference listViewResultsRowNumber}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CellNameConverter},  ConverterParameter='Column5'}"     
                               Text="{Binding DateSynced, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh\\:mm:ss tt}' }" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                               FontSize="Micro" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This will give you a unique AutomationId for every cell in every row in a ListView set up with a Grid like this:

- listViewResultsRow1.Column1
- listViewResultsRow1.Column2
- listViewResultsRow1.Column3
- listViewResultsRow1.Column4
- listViewResultsRow1.Column5
- listViewResultsRow2.Column1
- listViewResultsRow2.Column2
- etc